# Entry into Canada for Candian citizens during COVID-19 period

Tags: canada, international-travel, covid-19, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen and a permanent resident of the US.   Would I be allowed entry into Canada to visit my elderly and ailing father during COVID-19 border restrictions?

Answer (score 10):

Of course you can go to Canada; they can't refuse a citizen entry, not even for a pandemic. You will need to be able to prove your Canadian citizenship, ideally with your Canadian passport. You will be required to [self-isolate for 14 days](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/diseases/2019-novel-coronavirus-infection/latest-travel-health-advice.html#_Travellers_without_symptoms:) or be assigned to a place where you will be quarantined, if you do not have a place to self-isolate.

It is important to note that, during this quarantine period, you may not have any contact with "vulnerable people, such as people 65 years or older, or people with underlying medical conditions."

You also need to bring your green card so that you can return to the US.

Comment: It's actually not a given that Canadian citizens **who are not resident in Canada** will be allowed over the border. Some of the answers to the linked question indicate it may not be. And if you are allowed in it is far from certain you would be allowed back.

Comment: @DJClayworth They're also out of date.

Comment: @DJClayworth could you link to a Canadian government regulation which explicitly bans non-resident Canadians?

Comment: Indeed. The link above is to the _current_ regulations, as of today. They'll change, of course, but the post describes today's situation.

Comment: Links in the other answers. Several quotes that "nonessential travel is banned" but "Canadian citizens **returning** will beexempted.

Comment: I can't comment on if US will be allowed back, but Canadian citizens have been and are allowed to enter Canada, regardless of residency or presence COVID-19 symptoms. If you have symptoms, you will be denied boarding, but if you are at the border, they won't deny entry.

Comment: The news linked in the other question is misinterpreted, the reference to "extraordinary circumstances" is for Canadians wanting to enter US, it does not apply to Canadians wishing to enter Canada, which in any case is returning to one's home country, even if temporarily.

Comment: The actual [regulations](https://orders-in-council.canada.ca/attachment.php?attach=38958&lang=en) from day one have been very clear, only foreign nationals are prohibited from crossing US-Canada border into Canada, and "a foreign national means a person who is not a Canadian citizen or a permanent resident" with no reference whatsoever to residency.